# Find the water pumped to flowers using fractions.

Tags: fractions

A certain tank has water filled to $\frac{1}{5}$ of it's capacity. A persons opens a tap and allows the tank to fill upto to $\frac{3}{4}$ of it's capacity. Then he uses the water in the tank and finally $\frac{1}{3} $ water remains in the tank.

What I have found :

Water that was added to the tank after opening the tap : $\frac{11}{20}$

Fraction of water he used was : $\frac{5}{12}$

Total capacity of water in the tank : 1800 litres

Problem:

Find the amount water he used up in litres

How many more litres remained in the tank in the end when compared to the beginning

Comment: it seems like you have the fractions; are you having trouble converting those to litres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved it correctly. Just multiply the fractions by the tank capacity to find the volume of water.

> Find the amount water he used up in litres

$1800(3/4-1/3)=1800(5/12)=750L$

> How many more litres remained in the tank in the end when compared to
>   the beginning

$1800(1/3-1/5)=1800(2/15)=240L$